# Swift: Trigger function from AVAudioPCMBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, buffer

I am working on a Metronome app for iOS. The engine is working and it's very accurate at the moment, however, it is giving only audio feedback while I would like to give a visual feedback as well.

I made an AVAudioPCMBuffer to play a tick at the set intervals, how can I trigger a function whenever the audio is played?

Here is the code I have at the moment:

'''
private func generateBuffer(bpm: Double, beats: Int) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {

```
    audioFileMainClick.framePosition = 0
    audioFileAccentedClick.framePosition = 0
    
    let beatLength = AVAudioFrameCount(audioFileMainClick.processingFormat.sampleRate * 60 / bpm)
    let bufferMainClick = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFileMainClick.processingFormat, frameCapacity: beatLength)!
    try! audioFileMainClick.read(into: bufferMainClick)
    bufferMainClick.frameLength = beatLength
    
    let bufferAccentedClick = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFileMainClick.processingFormat, frameCapacity: beatLength)!
    try! audioFileAccentedClick.read(into: bufferAccentedClick)
    
    let bufferBar = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFileMainClick.processingFormat, frameCapacity: UInt32(beats) * beatLength)!
    bufferBar.frameLength = UInt32(beats) * beatLength
    
    let channelCount = Int(audioFileMainClick.processingFormat.channelCount)
    let accentedClickArray = Array(
        UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bufferAccentedClick.floatChannelData![0],
                            count: channelCount * Int(beatLength))
    )
    let mainClickArray = Array(
        UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bufferMainClick.floatChannelData![0],
                            count: channelCount * Int(beatLength))
    )
    
    var barArray = [Float]()
    // one time for first beat
    barArray.append(contentsOf: accentedClickArray)
    // n times for regular clicks
    for _ in 1...(beats - 1) {
        barArray.append(contentsOf: mainClickArray)
    }
    bufferBar.floatChannelData!.pointee.assign(from: barArray,
                                               count: channelCount * Int(bufferBar.frameLength))
    return bufferBar
    
}

func play(bpm: Double, beats: Int) {
    
    let buffer = generateBuffer(bpm: bpm, beats: beats)
    
    if audioPlayerNode.isPlaying {
        audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil, options: .interruptsAtLoop, completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        self.audioPlayerNode.play()
    }
    
    self.audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil, options: .loops, completionHandler: nil)
    
}
```

'''

thank you in advance.

Filippo

Answer (score 0):

Try *not* to use the loop function of scheduleBuffer. Use a completionHandler instead that re-triggers the play() function. This gives you the option of adding code to the play() function for visual feedback like displaying the current beat. And remember to always use DispatchQueue.main.async {...} for UI stuff.